# What is the role of a for loop in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, stack, variable-assignment

given the following pseudo - code (objArray(1) means that an Array with one entry has been created)

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = objArray(1)
    self.N = 0

  def __resize(self,capacity):
    copy = objArray(capacity)
    for i in range(self.N):
     copy[i] = self.data[i]
    self.data = copy
```

I do not understand how this is supposed to work. Let us go through this step by step:

First of all we create an array with 1 entry. We set N to 0. So far so good.

The next function initializes a variable `copy = objArray(capacity)`with a parameter. Also clear.

Now it is starting to get confusing to me. We initialized `N = 0` in our constructor. So the parameter for our range function is 0, right? And in python the range function, to my knowledge, reduces the parameter by 1. So would our range funtion go to -1? If I understood that maybe the role of the for loop might become more clear to me.

Comment: Perhaps you could conduct your own experiments like this: `for i in range(0): print(i)`. You will see that nothing is printed, so in the case of `N = 0` the loop becomes a `nop`.

Comment: Is your question simply what happens when  N is 0, or is it more broadly why the loop is there at all?  (It needs to be there when N is not 0, which can happen if the stack is resized more than once.)

Answer (score 0):

`range(0)` is empty; the `for` loop in your code will do nothing if `N == 0`.  If `N` is meant to represent the size of the stack, this is correct; if the stack is zero, there's nothing to copy, right?

Practically speaking, there's no reason to do this because your internal array probably tracks its own length:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []  # empty list

    def __resize(self, capacity: int) -> None:
        copy = [None] * capacity
        for i in range(min(len(self.data), capacity)):
            copy[i] = self.data[i]
        self.data = copy
```

This remains an awkward example because Python lists take care of resizing themselves and are already easily usable as stacks without needing to wrap them in a class, but hopefully it gives you a better idea of how `len` and `range` work.

Comment: Thank you. N counts the number of elements in the Stack. I also have the source code for the funktion `objArray(1)` and it states that an Array is created but the entry would be "None" in this case to demonstrate that there is no element in the stack. I hope that makes sense. Anyway thanks things are much clearer now.